# How do I send a contact via SMS?

Tags: contacts, sms

I would like to send two contacts (name+phone nr) to one of my contacts. This is a simple menu-option on my old Sony Ericsson.

How can I do this on Android?

I'm not in the same building as the receiver so I can not use Bluetooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For users with Ice Cream Sandwich:

Using the stock messaging app, you can attach contacts to the message either on "Text" or "vCard" formats.

### When writing the message:

1. Touch the device "menu";
2. Touch "Attach";
3. Touch "Contact";
4. Touch the desired method.
   You will then be presented with your contacts list to select the desired contact.

[image: Step 02] [image: Step 03] [image: Step 04]

<sup>*Screenshots taken from LG-P700 running Android v4.0.3.*</sup>

Comment: Leaving this here since many users don't realize that this method is not available on early versions of Android. Also to the ones that may end up here searching about this regarding newer versions.

Answer (score 8):

Surprisingly, you need a third party app.

http://www.appbrain.com/app/shareContacts.NS.com

Answer (score 3):

On HTC Desire HD (Froyo) whilst composing an SMS: **Menu** > **Attach** > **Contact(vCard)**

Or is that a HTC Sense feature?

Answer (score 3):

A new app from an XDA developer just hit the market: [Share Contacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=isoftmagic.share.contact)

> Share Contacts is an application to Send and Receive Contacts via SMS.
>   It provides facility to pic contacts from phone, customise it and send business card by SMS.
>   It can recognize the messages having business cards and provide facility to save them in Phone.
>
> Here are main features of application:
>
> - Send contacts by SMS.
> - Pick up contact information from saved contacts.
> - Send customised information.
> - Filter SMS with Business Cards.
> - Retrieve contact information from SMS.
> - Save retrieved contact information into Phone contacts.
> - Add contact with Google Sync.
> - Integrated with Phone application.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an add text > contact option when writing an sms?
I can do that in Galaxy S 2.1

Comment: No, I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you are looking for but I have been using ChompSMS for over a year now, and it's super awesome anyway, if you use that then there is a little plus icon to the left of the text input, clicking on it brings you a list of picture emoticons, saved templates, and contact insertion.
Another option is going to view contact in your phone book and then clicking menu and then share, but I think you were looking to send the info via sms which this doesn't appear to do on my htc inc w/ cy 7.03

Answer (score 1):

In your SMS app, click Settings => Add text => Contacts, then select your contact and press send.

Comment: What type of phone  are you using? I don't have this on my Galaxy Nexus, so it might be a non-standard function added by your device manufacturer (and if you can specify it may be more helpful for others with the same phone).

Answer (score 1):

Another third-party app for this, which I prefer: [Contacto's (share contacts)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.movinapp.contactos)

Answer (score 1):

[Contact Share by SMS Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dunitiapps.contactsharelite) may be for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very convenient way to send contacts in text format. Try [Contacts via Sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.huboltapps.contactsviasms): this app makes it easy to do so:

> Contacts via Sms enables you to send contacts and contact details as text via Sms (and via any other text application in next update ex: Skype, Viber, Chat, Google Drive, Dropbox, Notes etc).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your contact list -> pull up your menu -> share -> then via email or SMS etc..

Answer (score 1):

Friends, 
First I would like to draw your attention that there are two application used while typing.

1. If you used option menu then there is a one tab named inserts contacts which is used for sending contacts as a test message.
2. Second function is directly appear when you are start typing as a attachments or insert which is used for sending contacts as a MMS.

Generally we are using second option because its appear on screen easily.

Just check this I hope you will find your answer.